# Windows Phone 7 Image Looping

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I would like to loop through a sequence of images.  I have tried using a Pivot control, but I don't like the blank space in between image transitions.  I would prefer to use something that will animate between images smoothly.  I also looked at the LoopingSelector control, but I can't seem to set the orientation to horizontal.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you need. Can you make any example, links or show images of what you mean?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? (I know it was a while ago, but if you recall whether my answer was correct, I'd appreciate you marking it). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're interested in a kind of image viewer like iOS offers, swiping right or left to navigate through the photos. If that's the case, I hate to say it but i think you're looking at building your own control.

I think to implement it properly these are the essential things you need to think about and address:

- For performance' sake, load all the images you have into memorystream objects and store the binary data (you can get creative with this and only store the first 10-15 images, depending on how large the images are, doing this would enable your control to support thousands of images and still perform like a champ).
- Once an image is *about* to be on-screen set the source of the image to the saved memorystream object that has the bytes loaded into it (this will minimize the work that the UI thread does, keeping the control performant and responsive)
- Use Manipulation events to track the delta x of the motion someone uses when swiping left to right in order to actually perform the moving of the items
- Move the images by changing their Canvas.Left property (you can go negative I think, otherwise just make your canvas the width of all the images you have combined)
- Look up some of the available libraries to support momentum so you can have a natural smooth transition between images